# Generic NHibernate repository Contains(TId id) method

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a generic Repository that uses NHibernate where also the type of the ID is generic parameter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a common base class for repositories.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity"> The type of the entity. </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TId"> The type of the ID of the entity. </typeparam>
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : EntityBase<TEntity, TId>
```

How can I implement a nice generic `Contains` method that is fast and readable for NHibernate in this case?

```
public bool Contains(TId id)
{
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        // throws an excpetion that Equals is not supported
        return session.QueryOver<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id.Equals(id)).RowCount() > 0;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

NHibernate has lazyload turned off in my case.

Comment: How would that look like? TId is a generic parameter...

Comment: the standard criteria api takes a generic object

Comment: I think you can reformulate that to use e.g. WhereRestrictionOn() and Restrictions.Eq() to avoid mentioning Equals.

Comment: Btw, opening a new session in each repository method is generally a BIG no-no as it prevents proper use of caching, lazy-load and transactions.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in comments... use a criteria, using the "id" special property

```
public bool Contains(TId id)
{
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    { 
        return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("id", id))
            .SetProjection( Projections.Count("id"))
            .UniqueResult() > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I am not yet quite familiar with the underpinnings of NHiberntate but how can it NOT hit the database to check whether an entity exists? Only the DB has all the entities. Also: Wouldn't GetById take even more time because it would load the whole entity from the DB, whereas I all *actually* it would have to do is check wether the ID exists.

Comment: GetById is implemented this way: `session.Get<TEntity>(id)` this means it will get **all** columns of **all** connected tables **and** instanciate **all** connected child objects of the aggregate. Isn't that total overkill just to check for existance of an entity (ID)?

Comment: At the time of my first answer, the edit about lazy loading wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to override `Eqauls`, and other comparison operators in your entity base class, something like:

```
public abstract class TEntity
{
    public override bool Equals(object entity)
    {
        return entity != null
            && entity is EntityBase
            && this == (EntityBase)entity;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EntityBase base1, 
        EntityBase base2)
    {
        if ((object)base1 == null && (object)base2 == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object)base1 == null || (object)base2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (base1.Key != base2.Key)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(EntityBase base1, 
        EntityBase base2)
    {
        return (!(base1 == base2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I should to prefer not to have a `bool Contains(TEntity entity)` but a `bool Contains(TId id)`, because if NHibernate needs to use the .Equals of my Entity class, in the worst case wouldn' it have to load **all** entities from the DB and call `TEntity.Equals` for **each**.